# How do I determine the amount of genes that are mutated using a mutation operator?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, mutation

I am familiar with mutation techniques and have implemented some in my project, however I have never really known how many genes should be mutated when implementing a mutation operator. Let's take boundary mutation for example; we select a gene at random and replace it with either a lower or upper bound of that gene.

However, I am unsure of whether I should just mutate 1 gene, or mutate more of them. I have therefore thought of two approaches I believe are viable strategies:

1. Assign a random probability to every gene that determines if the
   gene will be mutated. Roll a dice for every gene and mutate it if
   lands within the probability. Then stop and go on to the next
   chromosome.
2. Pick one gene at random and mutate it. Then stop and go on to the
   next chromosome.

Am I in the right direction here? When should I prefer one strategy over the other? Or is there another way to determine the amount of genes to be mutated? Or is it problem-specific?

Comment: I'm actually writing a GA right now, and I'm opting for option 1; basically. The problem with option 2 is you have a constant mutation rate that's determined by the length of the chromosome. If it's 5 genes long, you'll have a 1/5 chance of a gene mutating.

Comment: I'm just scared that going with option 1 will result in wild mutations instead of subtle mutations, since in the worst case all of the genes will be mutated. I can curb the extremities by only doing subtle mutations, however. Thanks for your input!

Comment: I'm using a mutation rate of like 0.1% right now, so wild mutations are highly unlikely.

Comment: Do you mean that you use a 0.1% probability on all genes that they will be mutated? Or use it as a probability a mutation procedure would even be started? After which you calculate the probability of each gene mutating.

Comment: Each gene has a 0.1% chance (around) of being mutated. Every generation, each gene of each chromosome is given that chance to mutate, and I'm allowing the mutated gene to become *any* possible gene, not only the extremes. Not saying my way is the right way, but it's what I've been using.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you could compress this into an answer, I will upvote it as I find you have provided some valuable information!

Comment: This question is unfortunately borderline off topic, since it's really isn't about a specific code-related problem. Likely the only reason you haven't been down voted is the question is fairly well asked, and is semi-interesting. I'd rather not risk getting down voted. Good luck with your GA!

Comment: Oops, correction: I'm actually using a mutation chance of 0.5%, so slightly larger, but still extremely small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have never really known how many genes should be mutated...

No one knows. There is no optimal mutation rate/scheme.

> is there another way

Yes, there are many, many ways. In fact you can change the mutation rate or scheme whenever you want. No one is gonna stop you!

Generically, you can have a dynamic mutation rate, which imho is preferable.

> When should I prefer one strategy over the other?

There is a natural tradeoff between exploration vs Exploitation.  Exploration is high mutation rate, exploitation is low.  You choose. Good luck!